# Accessing object parameters from another object actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

in the following video:
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/actionscript-11-with-doug-winnie/communicating-between-classes-episode-52/

he have two instances of object communicating together, both objects were created from Flash profession, and they simply "talk" by using the dot notation.

my program creates the objects dynamically, how can I communicate from one class to another from within the created instances? the creation may be from the main .as file or from within an object created from Main,

is this even possible?

Comment: If the properties are public, other classes may communicate with them.

Comment: But they need a reference to the instance from that instance. How do you tell an instance about another instance, when you create the instance like you did in the video, each know about the other one.

Comment: Give each class a public property that you will use to reference the other object. When you create an instance, set the property of the instance to reference the other instance. Then you can use the dot notation syntax to call public methods or access public access modifiers of each instance.

Comment: Thanks karma, is there an example to demonstrate that?

Comment: I'd rather not because what you're asking sort of goes against OOP principals, and other devs will call me out on it. Objects should not be created with dependency on other objects. Can you give an example of your code so I know exactly what you're trying to do? Then I can advise you on the best solution.

Comment: what I am trying to do is add a menu programmatically. why does a menue need to be an object? there must be something wrong I am not understanding, in the video above an event calls a function buttonClick, which runs die1.rollDie(). the problem I have is that he added the die manually on the stage in flash, I am trying to add the object programmatically and access it as simple as object.function() to do stuff from anywhere possible.. what am I missing here? how do I create an shape in a sprite and interact with it in object.function() format?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't keep object reference, you may need a third class to be the bridge between the objects.

Here is an example

```
public class NotifyMgr
{
    private static var _instance:NotifyMgr = new NotifyMgr();

    public static function getInstance():NotifyMgr
    {
         return _instance;
    }

    //send a message
    public function sendMessage(msgType:String, data:*):void
    {

        var observers:Vector.<IObserver> = notifies[msgType] as Vector.<IObserver>;

        if (observers == null)
        {
              return;
        }

        for each (var obj:IObserver in observers)
        {
             obj.notify(msgType, data);
        }
    }

    private var notifies:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    //regiter a observer by msgType
    public function register(msgType:String, obj:IObsever):void
    {
         if (notifies[msgType] == null)
         {
             notifies[msgType] = new Vector.<IObserver>();
         }

         var observers:Vector.<IObserver> = notifies[msgType] as Vector.<IObserver>;

         if (obj != null && observers.indexOf(obj) == -1)
         {
              observers.push(obj);
         }
    }

    public function unRegister(msgType:String, obj:IObserver):void
    {
    }

}

/**
 *Your object should implement this interface
 */
public interface IObserver
{
    function notify(msgType:String, data:*):void;
}
```

So you could create object A and b that both implement interface IObserver, and register A in NotifyMgr, call NotifyMgr.sendMessage in B,then A will know it.

Comment: although the video show how it is easy when you create the objects and change the state between each other, this looks like it is difficult and is a hack to accomplish the same thing grammatically. because this example is woooosh, flies over my head...

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Design Patterns! http://www.amazon.com/ActionScript-3-0-Design-Patterns-Programming/dp/0596528469

Comment: This example is not a hack. This is how you would implement the functionality you want. Another option would be dependency injection.

Comment: Is there a proper way to create a two buttons programmatically, each from separate class, and be able to access each other? Like changing the text on the other button? I must be way off here, I am just trying to place a list on the stage with some interaction in a small program. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, Main is your Document Class, and Die is an extension of the Sprite Class. You can call its `rollDie()` method from within the Main Class because the access modifier is set to `public`

```
package{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite{

        public var die:Die;

        public function Main()
        {
            //create a die
            this.die = new Die();
            addChild(die);

            var button:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            addChild(button);
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
        }

        private function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            this.die.rollDie();
        }
    }

    /**
    * Die inherits from Sprite
    */
    public class Die extends Sprite {

        public function Die() {}

        public function rollDie():void 
        {
            var result:int = Math.ceil( Math.random()*6 );
            trace("rolling die: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```